# R Shiny stitch a number of htmloutput tables

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, googlevis

I have an R Shiny server running with several tabPanels. In one of the tabPanels, I have a list of `htmlOutput("sth")` that right now leave a large space between each of them:

```
tabPanel("MyPanel",
   htmlOutput("A"),
   htmlOutput("B"),
   htmlOutput("C"),
   htmlOutput("D"),
   htmlOutput("E"),
   htmlOutput("F"),
   htmlOutput("G")
         ),
```

On the `server.R` side, each of these is a `x$html$chart["jsDrawChart"]` with some manual javascript formatting done on them to colour the cells in the tables.

How can I combine these `htmlOutput` so that they are vertically stitch together, with no blank space left between them in the html page?